# iPhone 4 Filters won't show up on Instagram

Tags: iphone

When I take a photo with my camera and use a filter, I try to upload it to Instagram but it doesn't recognize the filter. It just shows the pic without the filter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known behaviour for pictures edited from camera or photos app on iOS. When you try to load the picture onto Instagram, It loads the original version of the picture (*without any filter*) that was taken.

If you want the picture with iOS Camera filters - Screenshot the picture once you apply the filter and load the screenshot-ed picture on Instagram.